# Matlab exe unable to read a file created in Java

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment

My goal is to execute Matlab executables from a Java program. To test this mechanism I have a Java program that takes input and writes the values to a file. The Matlab .exe is programmed to read the file and display the content. (Once this works fine I will proceed with major Matlab operations).

But unfortunately, I am unable the print the content of the file using the Matlab executable. 
Here is my Java code.

```
public class JavaMatlab_I_O 
{
    public void MatlabexeCall(String commandline) 
    {
        try 
        {
            String line;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandline);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            input.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception err) 
        {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        FileOutputStream fop = null;
        File file;
        String inp;
        System.out.println("Enter Data: ");
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        inp = obj.next();
        try 
        {
            file = new File("C:\\Users\\PritamDash\\Documents\\MATLAB\\TestFile2.txt");
            fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) 
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            // get the content in bytes
            byte[] contentInBytes = inp.getBytes();
            fop.write(contentInBytes);
            fop.flush();
            fop.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JavaMatlab_I_O test = new JavaMatlab_I_O();
        test.MatlabexeCall("C:\\Users\\PritamDash\\Documents\\MATLAB\\myfunc1.exe");

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Matlab code

```
function myfunc1()
    disp(importdata('TestFile2.txt'));
end
```

I generated exe using mcc

```
mcc -mv myfunc1.m
```

When I execute `!myfunc1.exe` in matlab command prompt it works fine. When I remove the file operation and use myfunc1.exe to simply print a String it works fine when called from Java. 
I am unable to identify why Java Program is unable to trigger the file read operation in Matlab  .exe

Comment: This works. Thanks for the suggestion.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your Matlab function to:

```
disp(importdata('C:\Users\PritamDash\Documents\MATLAB\TestFile2.txt'));
```

Comment: But If I execute the same .exe in another machine it wont work. Since the path is static.

Comment: You could create the text file to a fixed path in Java then you could use that path. I mean if you use e.g. C:\yourdirectory\xyz.txt, it shall exist.
It really depends on you use case.
Another possiblity to get the user directory programatically, to do this, this thread can help: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/149027

Comment: This one looks interesting. Thanks for your time.!